# How does movement speed work in game?

Tags: killing-floor-2

Does it matter if I run with a knife out or not? Does sprinting even do anything? I honestly feel as if sprinting barely increases your speed, but I don't even know if having a knife or other weapon out changes anything.  Would a lower weight weapon make you move faster? Is perk speed boost factored into sprint speed?

Comment: Sprinting increases speed and also FOV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. No, running with a knife does not increase your speed, unless you are the berserker class
2. Sprinting increases your speed.
3. Only total weight affects speed, the weapon you have out only matters if it is melee.
4. It is somewhat difficult to tell, but I tested it with a friend and it appears to affect sprint speed.

Comment: Can someone confirm whether certain attacks from enemies affect speed? At times it feels like speed dramatically drops with low health, being hit by sirens or being hit by bloats.

Comment: Health affects speed as well as being hit by sirens. I don't think bloats slow you, but I'm not sure about that one.

Comment: It is confirmed that that running with a knife does not change your speed; that is a Berserker only effect and doesn't apply to any other class.

Comment: So total weight affects the speed? because it seems that when I play support and max out on my weapons I seemed to be always the last to reach the trader even though we start sprinting at the same time.